# Tableview issue iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, tableview

Hi i am working on application which going to communicate over the ble(bluetooth low energy).In my Application initial Screen contain Tableview which show the device's near to my iPhone.

Consider 1 case At the time of lauch
Every thing is work fine core BLE give device's near to my application screen via delegate then my table view reload, table datasource get call first cellInSection then cellForRowAtIndex. And my table shows proper device List near by it.

Consider 2 case After navigating to few screen then come back to inital screen
coreble give device's near to my application screen via delegate then my table view reload, but only numberofcellInSection get call not cellForRowAtIndex. Due to which my tableview see empty.

After debug i find that array count for display the device list is also proper.

Short Summary of code flow

BLEManagerClass(delegate fire whenever device is near by,passes information to modelwrapper class)---->modelwrapper(has delegate which pass the information to device list class)---->devicelistScreen(reload a tableview inorder to display the device list near to iphone)

Below are code of various class

1) This class is BLE manger, it has delegate centralManager(central: CBCentralManager!, didDiscoverPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral!, advertisementData: [NSObject : AnyObject]!, RSSI: NSNumber!) which get call whenever any device near to the iPhone. At the end of function I fire a delegate named didUpdatePeripheralList(), it pass device info to my modelwrapper class.

```
    internal func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager!,     didDiscoverPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral!, advertisementData: [NSObject : AnyObject]!, RSSI: NSNumber!) {

    printLog(strFileName, "didDiscoverPeripheral : \(peripheral) data :\(advertisementData.description)")
    var dataDict = NSDictionary()
    dataDict = advertisementData

    var isServicePresent:Bool = false
    let serviceUUIDArray : AnyObject = (advertisementData as AnyObject).valueForKeyPath("kCBAdvDataServiceUUIDs")!

    //check whether devices scanned contains Battery,Glucose services
    if(serviceUUIDArray.containsObject(CBUUID(string: GLUCOSE_SERVICE_UUID)) &&
        serviceUUIDArray.containsObject(CBUUID(string: BATTERY_SERVICE_UUID))) {
            isServicePresent = true
    }
    else
    {
        isServicePresent = false
    }
    var peripheralName = String()
    if let val:String = advertisementData["kCBAdvDataLocalName"] as? String {
        // now val is not nil and the Optional has been unwrapped, so use it
        peripheralName = advertisementData["kCBAdvDataLocalName"] as! String
    }


    //if session is started retrieve the connected peripheral
    var objModelWrapper:CGM_ModelWrapper = CGM_ModelWrapper.sharedInstance
    if(objModelWrapper.appState == .SessionStarted || objModelWrapper.appState == .isWarmUpTimerStarted || objModelWrapper.appState == .isWarmUpTimerEnded || objModelWrapper.isInitialConnectionRequest == false) {
        if(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey(PERIPHERAL_UUID) != nil) {
            var storedIdentifier:String = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey(PERIPHERAL_UUID) as! String
            if(storedIdentifier == peripheral.identifier.UUIDString) {
                printLog(strFileName, "storedIdentifier is \(storedIdentifier) and peripheral.identifier.UUIDString: \(peripheral.identifier.description)")
                cgmPeripheralObj = CGM_Peripheral()
                cgmPeripheralObj.peripheral = peripheral
                cgmPeripheralObj.RSSIValue = RSSI

                //assign peripheral name
                if(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey(PERIPHERAL_NAME) != nil) {
                    cgmPeripheralObj.strPeripheralName = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey(PERIPHERAL_NAME) as! String
                }
                else
                {
                    cgmPeripheralObj.strPeripheralName = peripheralName
                }
                cgmPeripheralObj.txUUID = (peripheral as CBPeripheral).identifier.UUIDString
                self.stopScanningPeripheral()
                self.objCentralManager.connectPeripheral(peripheral as CBPeripheral, options: nil)
                self.cgmPeripheralObj.peripheral = peripheral

            }
        }
        else
        {
            self.scanForBLEPeripherals()
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(isServicePresent == true) {
            cgmPeripheralObj = CGM_Peripheral()
            cgmPeripheralObj.peripheral = peripheral
            cgmPeripheralObj.RSSIValue = RSSI
            cgmPeripheralObj.strPeripheralName = peripheralName
            cgmPeripheralObj.txUUID = peripheral.identifier.UUIDString
            //send model wrapper class the discovered peripheral device details using delegate
            self.delegateDataToModelWrapper?.didUpdatePeripheralList(cgmPeripheralObj)
        }
        else
        {
            printLog(strFileName,"device with glucose,battery & device info services not found")
        }
    }

}
```

2) This modelwrapper class which pass device to to device list screen(my App initial Screen) via modelWrapper_updatePeripherals which going to fire after every 5 sec.

```
   internal func didUpdatePeripheralList(peripheralObj: CGM_Peripheral)  {
    var isPeripheralPresent:Bool = false

    // reset the isSensorSettingTimerStarted flag
    self.isSensorSettingTimerStarted = false

    for ( var arrPeripheralObject:CGM_Peripheral) in self.arrDeviceList {
        if(peripheralObj.peripheral != nil && arrPeripheralObject.peripheral != nil) {

            if(peripheralObj.strPeripheralName != "" && arrPeripheralObject.strPeripheralName != "") {
                if(peripheralObj.strPeripheralName == arrPeripheralObject.strPeripheralName) {

                    isPeripheralPresent = true
                    break
                }
                else
                {
                    isPeripheralPresent = false
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if(isPeripheralPresent == false) {
        self.arrDeviceList.append(peripheralObj)
    }

    //created timer to clear and update the scanned device list
    if(updatePeripheralTimer == nil) {
        self.modelWrapper_updatePeripherals()
        updatePeripheralTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(5, target: self, selector: "modelWrapper_updatePeripherals", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

}
internal func modelWrapper_updatePeripherals() {
    self.delegateUpdateVCPeripheralList!.didUpdateVCPeriphralList(self.arrDeviceList)
    self.arrDeviceList.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

}
```

3) This is device list screen class has delegate function named didUpdateVCPeriphralList() in which I am reloaded the data.

```
    func didUpdateVCPeriphralList(arrDevice: Array<CGM_Peripheral>) {

    self.arrDevices = arrDevice
    if(arrDevice.count > 0) {
        //enable the btnConnectionWizard button
        self.btnConnectionWizard.enabled = true
        self.btnConnectionWizard.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    }
    else
    {
        self.btnConnectionWizard.enabled = false
        self.btnConnectionWizard.setTitleColor(hexStringToUIColor(kBUTTON_DISABLED_TEXT_COLOR), forState: UIControlState.Disabled)
    }

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
        printLog(self.strFileName,"before tablereload after peripheral scan \(self.arrDevices.count)")


        self.tableDeviceList.reloadData()

        for i in 0..<self.arrDevices.count {
            var deviceObj:CGM_Peripheral = self.arrDevices[i] as CGM_Peripheral
            if(deviceObj.strPeripheralName == self.selectedPeripheral.strPeripheralName) {
                let rowToSelect:NSIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: i, inSection: 0);
                self.tableDeviceList.selectRowAtIndexPath(rowToSelect, animated: true, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.None)
                printLog(self.strFileName, "table reloaded")
            }
        }
    });
}
```

please suggest if any one this issue before.

Comment: need. more. input.

Comment: can you please show some code?

Comment: If you called `reloadData`, which called your `numberOfRowsInSection`, but `cellForRowAtIndexPath` was not called, then `numberOfRowsInSection` must not have returned the value you think it should have. I'd add breakpoints and double check.

Comment: Hi rob i had check lot of time i found array count is not zero at time numberOfRowsInSection return. I had edit question with some code for better clarity.